# Sort data before using GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have read that grouping happens before ordering, is there any way that I can order first before grouping without having to wrap my whole query around another query just to do this?

Let's say I have this data:

```
id  | user_id | date_recorded
1   | 1       | 2011-11-07
2   | 1       | 2011-11-05    
3   | 1       | 2011-11-06
4   | 2       | 2011-11-03
5   | 2       | 2011-11-06
```

Normally, I'd have to do this query in order to get what I want:

```
SELECT
*
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date_recorded DESC
) t1
GROUP BY t1.user_id
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? You have no aggregate functions (`SUM(), AVG(), COUNT()`...) and there fore have no need for `GROUP BY`

Comment: If you are attempting to order first by date, then by user_id to have the users "grouped" together, that's simply a 2 part `ORDER BY` operation.

Comment: Just change your question to "Sorting Data before gouping", so that it will be specific to the need & useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear but I have a suspicion what you really want is not any `GROUP` aggregates at all, but rather ordering by date first, then user ID:

```
SELECT
  id, 
  user_id, 
  date_recorded
FROM tbl
ORDER BY date_recorded DESC, user_id ASC
```

Here would be the result. Note reordering by `date_recorded` from your original example

```
id  | user_id | date_recorded
1   | 1       | 2011-11-07
3   | 1       | 2011-11-06
2   | 1       | 2011-11-05    
5   | 2       | 2011-11-06
4   | 2       | 2011-11-03
```

**Update**

To retrieve the *full* latest record per user_id, a `JOIN` is needed.  The subquery (`mx`) locates the latest date_recorded per user_id, and that result is joined to the full table to retrieve the remaining columns.

```
SELECT 
  mx.user_id,
  mx.maxdate,
  t.id
FROM (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    MAX(date_recorded) AS maxdate
  FROM tbl
  GROUP BY user_id
) mx JOIN tbl t ON mx.user_id = t.user_id AND mx.date_recorded = t.date_recorded
```

Comment: let's say I want to get the single latest record for each user id only.

Comment: @voldomazta To get the complete latest record, a joined subquery will be needed. See my addition above.

Answer (score 0):

Iam just using the technique

**"Using order clause before group by inserting it in group_concat clause"**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(cast(id as char)
                                    ORDER BY date_recorded desc),',',1),
       user_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(cast(`date_recorded` as char)
                                    ORDER BY `date_recorded` desc),',',1)
FROM data
GROUP BY user_id
```